# php - how to detect if user is idle or inactive from browser

Tags: php

I've found this script that runs as a "TimeOut".
The scripts works fine, but before that, i want a php script to check if user is Inactive from Browser..

Is there a chance to do it using php?

```
if ($_SESSION['timeleft'] + 10 * 60 < time()) {
    echo '<script> window.location = "?logout";</script>';
}
```

Comment: Do you want to log the user out after a some time?

Comment: Define "inactive" for starters… does silently staring at the screen reading and comprehending the information on your webpage count…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP isn't really built for that, you can use JavaScript and make AJAX calls to a PHP page updating it with user activity.

An accepted way to do what you're apparently trying (use a dynamic session which logs people out after X seconds of inactivity), is to send such an update on every call to the server. If your site is synchronous (i.e. not a one-page application), you can expect users to navigate to different pages so this code can be in the page header.

If you have a one-page application, or expect users to stay on the same page for a long time (nowadays quite common), you can send an AJAX request every X seconds that updates the server.

WordPress takes both approaches, for example.